# Do I need a new zone for each domain I have on my server?

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I currently have a working BIND nameserver Running on my dedicated ubuntu server box. 
I have one zone set up.. example.com with its own nameservers.

If I want to add a new domain to point to the server, can I somehow add it to the existing zone? Or do I have to create a new zone and setcoms nameservers to example.com?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, see also http://serverfault.com/questions/443684/setting-up-bind-with-wildcard-nameserver and http://serverfault.com/questions/444060/dns-servers-designed-for-domain-parking

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to. But you can point to the same zone-file, if you want to.

Let's assume you have the following `named.conf` at the moment:

```
zone "example.com" in {
        type master;
        file "example.com.zone";
        allow-query { any; };
};
```

and the following `example.com.zone`:

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA ns.example.com. hostmaster@example.com. ( 
        2012061001 ; serial 
        8H ; refresh 
        2H ; retry 
        1W ; expiry 
        11h) ; minimum 

        IN      NS      ns1.example.com. 
        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

        IN      A       127.0.0.1
*       IN      A       127.0.0.1
ns1     IN      A       127.0.1.1
ns2     IN      A       127.0.2.1
```

You can safely add

```
zone "example.org" in {
        type master;
        file "example.com.zone";
        allow-query { any; };
};
```

to your `named.conf` and your bind will serve `example.org` with the settings of `example.com`.